# history.js confusion

Tags: jquery, ajax, history.js

I am totally new to AJAX and history.js.  I want to make a basic site that uses AJAX to change the content area when a nav item is clicked, preserve back button functionality as well as allow the user to type in the direct URL, such as mysite.com/page2, and have it load page2 in the content area.

I have no idea what I'm doing but history.js ([as seen here](https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify)) looks like what I need.  In testing it out, I have no idea where to go from here.  Any help is greatly apprecieted!

--Edited jQuery script

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery ScrollTo Plugin -->
    <script defer src="http://balupton.github.com/jquery-scrollto/scripts/jquery.scrollto.min.js"></script>
    <!-- History.js --> 
    <script defer src="http://balupton.github.com/history.js/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js"></script>
    <!-- This Gist -->
    <script defer src="http://gist.github.com/raw/854622/ajaxify-html5.js"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).bind("statechange", function(e) {
            var State = window.History.getState();
            if (window.console && window.console.log) {
                console.log("popstate", State, window.location.href);
            }
            $("#changehere").text(typeof State.data.changehere !== 'undefined' ? State.data.changehere : State.url);
            $('.nav').click(function() {
                alert(this);
                window.History.pushState({changehere:this}, this + 'title', '?' + this);
            })
        })
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #one {
            height: 300px;
            width: 1000px;
            background: #a0a0a0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="one">
        <a href="xml/first.html" id="first">change1</a>
        <a href="xml/second.html" id="second">change2</a>
        <a href="xml/third.html" id="third">change3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="changehere">
        start
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to intercept all clicks on relative links and call a History.pushState for each click. See https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify.

The relevant part is:

```
    $.fn.ajaxify = function(){
        // Prepare
        var $this = $(this);

        // Ajaxify
        $this.find('a:internal:not(.no-ajaxy)').click(function(event){

            // Prepare
            var
                $this = $(this),
                url = $this.attr('href'),
                title = $this.attr('title')||null;

            // Continue as normal for cmd clicks etc
            if ( event.which == 2 || event.metaKey ) { return true; }

            // Ajaxify this link
            History.pushState(null,title,url);
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });

        // Chain
        return $this;
    };
```